# Trouble including parameters in Rscript shebang line

Tags: r, linux, command-line

I am trying to write an R script that will run as an executable in linux. I don't want to print out the regular startup message when I run the script or run my .Rprofile. However, I'd like that handled within the script and not need R-specific parameters.

I've searched around online and most guides say to put `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript --vanilla` at the top. However, this is throwing an error:

```
(base) balter@spectre:~$ cat readinr.R
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript --vanilla

print("hello")
(base) balter@spectre:~$ ./readinr.R
/usr/bin/env: ‘Rscript --vanilla’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines
(base) balter@spectre:~$ R --version
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

- https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/11/r-scripts-as-command-line-tools/
- https://blog.sellorm.com/2017/12/18/learn-to-write-command-line-utilities-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

While the error message is a bit cryptic, [stackexchange is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477651/561890) more helpful. You need to use the -S flag in the shebang line

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S Rscript --vanilla
cat("Also, not hello")
```